# Create HTML Class and filter it by dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to HTML (just started learning at school) and I have a small question about classes and the ability to filter them.

Basicially, I'm working on a page of football fixtures, which will look as followed:

*TEAM NAME* *COMPETITION* *VENUE* *ATTENDANCE*

But I need to be able to select a dropdown menu and filter it by the competition, e.g. League/Cup/Friendly.

I know how to add the text and create the dropdown menu, but I'm not sure in how to define each line so that I can later filter it in the dropdown menu.

So for a more detailed example..

Manchester City   Cup   Home    28,000
Tottenham   League   Away   35,000

So I would like to be able to filter the above into competition. So user can select *League* and only see the Tottenham game etc.

Apologies if this question isn't worded very well.

Alternatively, if you can send me some links which will point me in the right direction I would appreciate that also.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Displaying the relevant source code and attempts would be a good start. If you haven't tried anything then i recommend you do some research, make an attempt, come back when you have a specific issue. Most people who help on stackoverflow will ignore this due to being school home work and no attempts made/shown of your own.

Comment: It's not home work actually we are in a term break and I'm creating random things to help when I go back. I'll put what up what I've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [bootstrap accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion)